# Codeigniter always return error message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to convert the codeigniter form handling using ajax then display validation error if validation is false but in my current state, it always throw an error. Check the code below for reference.

PHP:

```
 public function add () {

  $post_data = $this->input->post('formdata');
  $data = array (
    'identity' => $post_data ['email'],
    'password' => $post_data ['password'],
    'email' => $post_data ['email'],
    'group' => array($post_data['group_id']),
    'additional_data' => array (
      'first_name' => $post_data['first_name'],
      'last_name' => $post_data['last_name'],
      'active' => $post_data['active'],
      'date_registered' => date('Y/m/d h:i:sa')
      )
    );

    // custom error message
    $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_dash_space', '%s appears to be invalid. Must contain only alphabets.');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', '%s does not match the Confirm Password field. ');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
      $result['data'] = $this->ion_auth->register($data['identity'], $data['password'], $data['email'], $data['additional_data'], $data['group']);

    } else {
      $result['message'] = validation_errors();
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
 }
```

JS:

```
function submit_form (form_id) {
  var url      = $(form_id).attr("action");
  var formData = {};
  $(form_id).find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $(form_id).find('select[name]').each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $(form_id).find('textarea[name]').each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'formdata': formData
    },
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.data) {
      console.log(success);
        swal({
        title: "Success!",
        text: "You've done it great!",
        type: "success"
      },
      function(){
        location.reload();
      });
      } else {
        $('#error-msg').html(result.message);
      }
    },

    error: function(data) {
      swal({
        title: "Error!",
        text: "Oops, something went wrong. Check and try again.",
        type: "error"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Note: Form validation are set in config directory. So no issues in form rules. All are running good except I think the jquery that handles the condition.

Comment: Show the error generated by this code

Comment: @Arun, the `validation_errors();`

Comment: Try echo ing all the values and compare with validation rules

Answer (score 1):

Edit like below:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
       $result['message'] = validation_errors();
    } else {
       $result['data'] = $this->ion_auth->register($data['identity'],          
       $data['password'], $data['email'], $data['additional_data'],   
       $data['group']);
    }
```

Also you have `set_message` but not `set_rules`. If you want to use `form_validation` library, you should set some rules.

Comment: Hi, I understand what you mean but the form rules are set inside my config directory for cleaner codes. I repeat there's no issue in validation rules. The main issue I guess is the jquery and ajax

Comment: Can you add `console.log(formData);` under `success: function(result) {` then please tell me the print.

Comment: It gives me the object and contains the values of every fields I input. I noticed that everything inside the `if(result.data)` codes won't work.